# PHP POST with duplicate input names

Tags: php, html

I have checkbox inputs like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="service_options[]" value="it_maintenance" />
```

and then when i post the form, this code:

```
foreach($_POST["service_options"] as $so) {
    if($so) {
        echo 'yes';
    } else {
        echo 'no';
    }
}
```

it is working fine for when checkboxes are checked and it echoes 'yes' but if the checkbox is not checked, the 'no' does not show

Comment: then what you have to show??

Comment: If the checkbox isn't checked, the corresponding `$_POST` value isn't sent, that's why `no` is never echoed.

Comment: It does not show, because, when you don't have the value in $_POST["service_options"], then how will it fulfill the foreach() condition. it will break foreach loop.

Comment: check for a blank value first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkbox only post when enabled. The usual way of getting around this is to include a hidden input with the FALSE value. The form will post the LAST input's value, so make sure to place the hidden before the checkboxes:

```
<input type="hidden" name="service_options[1]" value="no" />
<input type="checkbox name="service_options[1]" value="yes" />
```

This way each record will always be present in the post. Make sure to actually name each checkbox/hidden pair, as they must have the same name for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

For this, its not necessary to break the array, just check the array:

```
$check = $_POST["service_options"];

if($check) {
       echo 'yes';
  } else {
       echo 'no';
  }
```

Hope, it will help you.

Comment: From what I've gathered from OP's question, it seems there are multiple checkboxes. You should adapt your code to check each one.

Comment: But how will we identify that for which option, present in the checkbox, it is displaying yes & no. I hope, you are understanding, what i want to say.

Comment: I understand what you mean, have a look at my answer `;)`

Comment: @roberto06 thanks bro, still i need to learn a lot, I hope one day i would be able to solve problems like this. But anyways, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Refere to Prateek Verma's comment above

> *It does not show, because, when you don't have the value in `$_POST["service_options"]`, then how will it fulfill the foreach()
>   condition?*

To solve this you need to check first if whether the checkbox is checked, then if its checked then start the loop. else show `no`

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        if (isset($_POST['service_options'])) {
            foreach ($_POST["service_options"] as $so) {
            }
            if ($so) {
                echo 'yes';
            }
        } else {
            echo 'no';
        }
    }
    ?>
    <form method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" name="service_options[]" value="it_maintenance" />
        <button type="submit" name="submit">ad</button>
    </form>
```

**update :**

From your comment below my answer which states :

> i basically want to know whether the user has unchecked the box if it
>   was already checked and if they have checked the box if it was not
>   already checked

I have done another method that is very quick and easy, I have used ajax to do what you want to do when the checkbox is checked/unchecked we send ajax to the php script and it will bring us results, now when a user checks we gonna see `yes` when they unchecked we will get `no` as our response.

**html side.**

```
<script  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<form method="post">
<input type="checkbox" name="service_options[]" value="it_maintenance" id="sevices" />

</form>

<div id="response"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $('document').ready(function(){

        $('#sevices').click(function(){

               var formData = $('form').serialize();
                    $.ajax({

                        type : 'post',
                        data : formData,
                        url  : 'checkbox.php',
                        dataType : 'json',
                        encode : true,
                        success : function(data){
                            if(data == "yes"){
                                //its check print back
                                $('#response').html(data);
                            }else{

                                //not checked print still

                                $('#response').html(data);

                            }
                        },
                    });

        });

        });
</script>
```

**server side : checkbox.php**

```
<?php

    if (isset($_POST['service_options'])) {
        foreach ($_POST["service_options"] as $so) {
        }
        if ($so) {
            $message =  'yes';
        }
    } else {
        $message =  'no';
    }

    echo json_encode($message);

?>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: i basically want to know whether the user has unchecked the box if it was already checked and if they have checked the box if it was not already checked

Comment: you should have said that on your question. you will need to use js. I will update

Comment: maybe i should use select inputs instead to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you have several checkboxes, as such :

```
<input type="checkbox" name="service_options[]" value="it_maintenance" />
<input type="checkbox" name="service_options[]" value="foo" />
<input type="checkbox" name="service_options[]" value="bar" />
```

First, you need to check if none of them are checked, then you need to check each value :

```
<?php
$possible_values = array('it_maintenance', 'foo', 'bar');
if (!isset($_POST['service_options'])) {
    echo 'None selected';
} else {
    foreach ($possible_values as $val) {
        if (in_array($val, $_POST['service_options'])) {
            echo $val . ' selected';
        } else {
            echo $val . ' not selected';
        }
    }
};
?>
```

Comment: The OP have new requirement *i basically want to know whether the user has unchecked the box if it was already checked and if they have checked the box if it was not already checked*

Answer (score -2):

If your checkbox is unchecked, then it will not be present on POST

If still you want to check for the presence of the checkbox on POST, ou might as well use:

```
foreach($_POST["service_options"] as $so) {
    if(isset($so)) {
        echo 'yes';
    } else {
        echo 'no';
    } 
}
```

Comment: You'll want to check if the `service_options` is set, instead of jumping straight into a foreach.